# XAMPP running a second MySQL on Windows

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a MySQL installation on my windows machine I want to keep untouched. It starts as a service. With my XAMPP I want to use a second MySQL instance. I changed ports and the server id (line 69 in my.ini and line 11 in config.inc.php) but I still cant start MySQL properly.

[image: xampp]